# Route VM Ware/VirtualBox traffic through VPN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, vmware

I have a few VMWare (Workstation 16) and VirtualBox VMs running on both MacOS and Windows hosts. I need to route their traffic through my VPN provider, Nord, in a transparent manner, without the VMs being aware of it (for example, by configuring the VPN inside the virtual machines).

To achieve this, I have done the following steps:

1. Set up a [Gluetun](https://github.com/qdm12/gluetun) proxy to forward traffic to Nord's servers. This is setup in the host machine.
2. Configure and assign an IP address to a [Tun2socks](https://github.com/xjasonlyu/tun2socks) network interface that connects to the aforementioned proxy. Again in the host machine.

However, I am unsure about the next steps regarding routing all the traffic from my VMs through the created network interface using IP rules or through another bridge interface. My hopes were to be able to provide my VMs a bridge adapter to the tun2socks interface but that does not appear as an option in VM Ware of VirtualBox. Could you please guide me on how to achieve this on both Windows and Mac? Moreover, I would appreciate any comments and suggestions on whether this is the most effective approach.

---

Comment: The most effiective would be installing vpn on the router which provide the internet to your machines. Then you won't need any extra software or configuration on your machines or vms.

Comment: What if I don't have access to the router or the router doesn't support VPN bridging? Doing this configuration from the host machine would make it very flexible.

Comment: Then buy a cheap $40 router which can do this. It will be very flexible.

Comment: why not just use VMware Workstation's NAT?  The VMs using that will piggyback on the host's connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I setup a VM as a virtual router for the other VMs. Here's the main idea:

1. Create a LAN network in VM Ware or VirtualBox (it’s called LAN Segment in VM Ware and internal network in VirtualBox) and put all machines (virtual router and VMs you want handled by it) in it. This way all machines will have an ethernet adapter through which they can communicate (as if they were connected through a switch). This adapter does not provide internet access.
2. Give the virtual router an additional NAT network adapter so that it can access the internet through it.
3. Configure the virtual router to route all of its traffic through a VPN provider’s servers and to work as a router for the other VMs.

With this setup, I tried 3 different configurations ([documented here](https://rafagarci.github.io/tutorials/vm-router/)). For most people, the easiest and most convenient one might be to configure a [pfSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PfSense) VM as the virtual router.